# Does the distribution of a dynasty trust count as income for purposes of chapter 7 bankruptcy?

Tags: united-states, income, bankruptcy, trusts

Assume a person is one of the beneficiaries of a [dynasty trust](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/d/dynasty-trust.asp) fund. The dynasty trust is [irrevocable](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/i/irrevocabletrust.asp) and perpetual, set in a US state that allows perpetual trusts. Annual distribution of the trust to this person is above the legal limit to file for chapter 7, maybe forcing her to file under chapter 13.

Being irrevocable, the trust fund cannot be used to settle the debts.

But do the trust fund distributions count as income on [form 122A-1](https://www.uscourts.gov/sites/default/files/form_b122a-1.pdf)?

Comment: What did your lawyer say?

Comment: @PeteB. That's a nice point, really (no sarcasm intended). I'm not seeking legal advice, I'm seeking a stack answer regarding a personal finance issue for non-binding purposes. If I had a real lawyer's opinion, I'd post said answer but alas, I don't.